# Firebase deploy blank page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

Both public/index.html & src/app/build/index.html are the same

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <title>React Redux App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My project tree

[image]

Incognito Console Log

[image]

I tried deleting **%PUBLIC_URL%/** then deploy, no errors but still blank page

[image]

Comment: Firebase is deploying the `build` folder at the top of your screenshot and not the one where you have selected index.html. Can you share a bigger picture of your directory structure? `"public": "build"` in Firebase JSON is looking for build directory right at root of the Firebase project directory.

Comment: I've updated the image @Dharmaraj